# Intellij plugin keymap first-stroke value

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, keymapping

I have implemented a plugin that I would now like to use. However, I do not understand and did not see clear documentation on how to assign keyboard shortcuts. I would like to activate it on a alt + enter key combination, but its not obvious what my keyboard-shortcut entry should be.

```
<keyboard-shortcut keymap="Mac OS X" first-keystroke="???"/>
```

I have the "Mac OS X" keymap set in preferences.

Comment: There is detailed [documentation](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/action_system.html) about this. Have you consulted it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortcut for Alt-Enter is written as "alt ENTER". You can look at the [default keymaps](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/platform/platform-resources/src/keymaps) as an example for defining other keyboard shortcuts.

Note that Alt-Enter is already used by the quickfix menu in IntelliJ IDEA, so it may not be a good idea to use the same shortcut for your own action. If you want to extend the Alt-Enter menu, there are other mechanisms for that (intention actions).

Comment: the default keymaps link was exactly what I needed.